# Error in Function evaluation

Tags: verilog

```
module ff(fv,a,b,c);
output [9:0]fv;
input [4 : 0] a,b,c;  
reg [4 : 0] x[9 : 0];
reg [9 : 0] np[9 : 0];
reg [4:0] newpop;
reg [4 : 0] y;

genvar i;

initial
begin
   x = { 4, 7, 2, 5, 4, 5, 9, 3, 0, 2 };  
end

  //assign fv = ((a*x*x)-(b*x)+c);

for (i=0; i<10; i=i+1)
begin
  y = x[i];
  always @ (y)
  newpop <= fitf(y,a,b,c);
  assign np[i] = newpop;
end
function automatic integer fitf;     
input [4:0] Y,A,B,C;
begin
  fitf = ((A*Y*Y)-(B*Y)-C);
end
endfunction
endmodule
```

I am trying to evaluate the function and store values in a array. This is the code i wrote but i get an error in line no 19. please help me out

Comment: Your code seems very unclear. Update code and tell us what you want actually

Comment: ** Error: E:/Softwares/installed/New folder/modelsim_ase/examples/Fun_prac.v(19): near "=": syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting "IDENTIFIER" or "TYPE_IDENTIFIER" or '#' or '('      i got this error at line no 19 " y = x[i];"

Answer (score 2):

Generate for-loops are unraveled at compile time. Assignments must be inside a procedural block or assign statement; the `begin`-`end` of a generate statement do not count as a procedural block. Therefore `y = x[i];` is illegal syntax. `reg` types must only be updated with in one always block to be synthesize, they cannot be assigned with `assign` statements in Verilog (okay in SystemVerilog).

Try putting everything onto one always block.

```
integer i;
always @* begin
  for (i=0; i<10; i=i+1) begin
    np[i] = fitf(x[i],a,b,c);
  end
end
```

Comment: Well done - you have managed to _unravel_ this code and produce a far more helpful answer than I could manage.

Answer (score 1):

`y = x[i];` is a procedural statement. It belongs *inside* an `initial` or `always` block. You have it outside. What's more, `y` is a `reg`; you cannot assign to a `reg` from outside  an `initial` or `always` block.

Comment: thanks both of you the problem is solved but code is still not working now i am facing error in array. illegal reference to x

Comment: I think you need to post a new question - that isn't enough to go on.  Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can easily reproduce your error.